# '403 Forbidden' when publishing a post containing different blocks

Tags: posts, block-editor, api

I'm experiencing a werid issue I never ran into before. I'm on WordPress 6.3.1 and each time I try to publish a post on my blog I get the "*Updating failed. The response is not a valid JSON response.*" notice and `POST {my_site}/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/{post_ID}?_locale=user 403 (Forbidden)'` related to `api-fetch.min.js` on the browser's console.

Here's a few more info and an overview of what I already tried without success.

- No matter if I write a post from scratch or copy-paste the content: **as soon as I add a non-text block** (which can be a separator, an image or a YouTube embed) between two blocks, **it doesn't publish**.
- I'm using the default editor (Block Editor, aka Gutenberg). **No page editor plugins installed.**
- I temporarily **deactivated all plugins and themes** and cleared the browser's cache.
- I tried with **different WP site accounts** and roles (admin, editor, author).
- I used **different browsers** with all extensions disabled, from different devices and networks / locations as well.
- I **sanitized all paragraphs** and strings.
- User is **still logged in**, session didn't expire.
- If I save the post as a **draft**, **no errors** are returned.
- If I place an image block or a non-text block **to the very end of the post**, **I'm able to publish it** successfully with no errors. If I move that block between two paragraph blocks, I get 403 when trying to publish.
- I'm able to **successfully publish posts containing text and heading blocks only**.
- If I leave the editor open without saving, the **browser's console** returns `POST {my_site}/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 415 (Unsupported Media Type)` referring to `jquery.min.js?ver=3.7.0:2` as well. Not sure if it's related.
- In the 403 call details, HTML returned in the `Content` key of the request payload is valid and doesn't contain weird char or tags. `Response` returns an HTML page that doesn't seem to be related to WordPress (but not sure), showing "*Error — You do not have permission to access this document*".
- There's **no firewall app or security measure** at server / hosting level.
- This issue appeared recently but I have no clue about **when** precisely and **what** may have caused it.

Any idea what else I can check? I'm running out of options.

Comment: is the user still logged in? This can happen if you leave the block editor open for a long time and you're logged out or your session expires behind the scenes, you can also look at the request in the dev tools and see what the response was, not just its HTTP header code but the HTML it returned, this can tell you if it's a plugin or host level firewall/security software/etc. Additionally, the block editor uses the REST API but your question mentions the old `admin-ajax.php`, and doesn't include the action and other parameters it was called with that might give clues, can you edit that in?

Comment: @TomJNowell Thanks for your suggestions. Yes, user is still logged in and session is active. On the Request Payload, the `Content` key has valid HTML and the response returns `Server Error — You do not have permission to access this document.`. Regarding `admin-ajax.php`, I can't find any additional info apart from what I reported above, but that's likely unrelated to the 403 issue and it randomly occurs. I updated the thread with additional details, BTW.

Comment: It's very likely that `admin-ajax.php` is super critical to this, requests to that file _always_ have an action parameter that tells it which AJAX handler to call, a critical clue to which code is responsible and where to look next. I guarantee the information is in your browser dev tools, look at the network tab. Also when you say "You do not have permission to access this document" can you be more specific? e.g. is it in a WP Die box with a gray background? An Nginx message? An Apache message? Does it list server or software names and versions? CDNs? Domains/URLs? Are parts in H2/H3's?

Comment: Also it would be helpful to isolate testing to a specific block that you can name, ideally one that's a part of core. It's also unlikely that the message about unsupported media type is the full message, a stack trace would be helpful, as well as an explanation of what you meant by "I sanitized all paragraphs and strings.". Avoid describing things in favor of screenshots and direct copy pastes, avoid stripping out parts that look unnecessary ( unhelpfully helpful ) such as informational messages before/after that don't look relevant.

Comment: also err on the side of specificity, e.g. instead of non-text block, put a code block and copy paste an example of raw block markup that has the issue

Comment: @TomJNowell I'm unable to reproduce the `415 (Unsupported Media Type)` issue right now. Unlike the `403 Unauthorized`, I don't know what triggers it. About the 403 response, "Server Error" is a <h1>, "Forbidden" is a <h2> and the rest is inside a <p>. It's a basic page with white background and it's not a `wp_die` notice. I suppose it's Nginx's, but it doesn't mention or contain anything else at all. Core blocks causing this issue are, for instance, separator or image. By "I sanitized all paragraphs" I mean that I used a tool to strip any chars or entities to make sure the post is all text.

Comment: @TomJNowell The 403 stack trace is super long. It's plenty of `(anonymous) @` referring to `api-fetch.min.js`, `core-data.min.js`, `data.min.js`, `redux-routine.min.js`, `editor.min.js` and `react-dom.min.js`.

Comment: @TomJNowell Regarding raw block markup, if I add a separator block whose HTML is just `<hr class="wp-block-separator has-alpha-channel-opacity"/>` before the last paragraph, I get a 403. If I move it to the very end of the post, everything works fine and I'm able to publish the post.

Comment: hmm are you sure there's no security software at the host level? An Nginx level response implies that. This could still be the REST API nonce expiring and requiring a refresh, if so refreshing the page would resolve the issue, and it would also imply that the non-text block part of your question is coincidental. Note that raw block markup starts and ends with a HTML comment stating the block type and its attributes

Comment: @TomJNowell I confirm that a refresh or a hard reload doesn't solve the issue. After I get a 403, if I just remove the non-text block, publishing works as expected. Anyway, I'll triple check security settings with my hosting provider and update this thread.

Comment: @TomJNowell I found a solution and posted it as answer. Thanks a lot for all your help, much appreciated. Understanding that the 403 response was returned at host level was crucial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After carefully checking the hosting settings again, I found out that Plesk's firewall was too restrictive. Each API call was going through it and — in most cases — any non-text block was mistakenly detected as `WordPress Unauthenticated Content Injection vulnerability`, for some reason. I noticed it in the firewall's log.

Whitelisting Gutenberg in the rules set and changing the firewall mode to "Detection only" fixed the issue.

[image: Firewall settings in Plesk]

Not sure if a Plesk's update caused it. Nobody changed the firewall rules recently and the 403 issue appeared only a few days ago. I'll report it to Plesk, in case it's a bug.